# Не подключается memcached с удаленного сервера.

Tags: php, memcached, debian

Конечно же для связки с php.
Установили на два сервера. На локальном отлично работает, на удаленный не можем достучаться.
В конфигах ничего не менялось, уже второй день смотрю интернеты, не пойму как разрешить доступ. Может быть фаерволл блокирует?
Сервера на debian.

$this->memcache->addServer(localhost, 11211);
$this->memcache->addServer(5.*.*.*, 11211); - не конектит. * скрытые цифры.

Установили так же утилиту phpmemcachedadmin, там создаем стек, не конектит.
Очевидно, что доступ что-то блокирует. Или надо что-то прописать в конфиг (сейчас он стандартный или как посмотреть фаерволл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

решено.
тут описание как решил
http://seyferseed.ru/linux/nastrojka-memcached-v-debian-dlya-php-na-neskol-kih-serverah.html